# How to prevent external Enum to string conversion when annotated with JsonStringEnumConverter

Tags: c#, json, .net, enums

I am using Microsoft Graph package, which contains a lot of enums annotated with JsonStringEnumCoverters. For example consider such enum:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum SomeEnum
{
    First = 1,
    Second = 2
}
```

I use this enum as property type in class whose objects are serialized. Obviously, such properties are serialized to strings and I get something like `"{ "value": "First" }"`, when desired result is `"{ "value": 1 }"`.

How can I override this behaviour?

Comment: What happens when you remove the attribute?

Comment: @HereticMonkey This enum is in library, I cannot edit this code

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own converter:

```
public class SomeEnumConverter : JsonConverter<SomeEnum>
{
    public override SomeEnum Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type type, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        SomeEnum? result = null;
        var value = reader.GetString();
        if (int.TryParse(value, out int intval)) {
            result = (SomeEnum)intval;
        }
        else {
            if (Enum.IsDefined(type, value)) {
                result = (SomeEnum)Enum.Parse(type, value);
            }
        }
        return result.Value;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, SomeEnum value, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options) 
        => writer.WriteStringValue(((int)value).ToString());
}
```

Now, you can decorate a class Property of type `SomeEnum` with:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SomeEnumConverter))]
```

in this case, only properties decorated with `JsonConverter` are handled by the custom converter, otherwise the predefined conversion is applied.

or use [JsonSerializerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions) to specify a JsonConverter for the `SomeEnum` type. E.g.,:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() {
    WriteIndented = true
};
options.Converters.Add(new SomeEnumConverter());
```

In this case, all properties of type `SomeEnum` are handled by the custom converter.

Test with:

```
var testClass = new SomeClass(SomeEnum.Third, true);
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(testClass, options);
var testClassNew = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SomeClass>(json);
```

Note that if you pass a value that is not defined, e.g.:

```
var testClass = new SomeClass((SomeEnum)5, true);
```

the Property value will be serialized and deserialized as the integer representation (`5`).

Sample class (the empty Constructor is required):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass() { }
    public SomeClass(SomeEnum enu, bool value) {
        this.SomeValue = enu;
        this.Other = value;
    }

    // Uncomment if JsonSerializerOptions are not used or
    // you want to apply the converter to some but not all properties
    // [JsonConverter(typeof(SomeEnumConverter))]
    public SomeEnum SomeValue { get; set; }
    public bool Other { get; set; }
}
```